# Assign Network Security Group to a Network Interface using ARM PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

Starting from the code below I'm trying to add the security group $nsg to the network interface $interface
The current value of $interface.NetworkSecurityGroup is null

The security group and the newtork interface arealready created. How do I assign the security group to the network interface?

```
$resourceGroupName = "evoeitrg"
$interfaceName = "evoeitinterface"
$securityGroupName = "NsgWebServer"

$interface = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $interfaceName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$nsg = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $securityGroupName
```

Comment: The security group is already created. my problem is to assign the security group to an existing interface. Trust my I've tried, I don't ask questions lightly here.

Comment: That's all right, I have a fallback where I could give the NSG id as a parameter in New-AzureRmNetworkInterface , but I think there should be way to do this post-create

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be what you're looking for

```
$sg = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup
$nic1 = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name testnic `
                     -ResourceGroupName $rg `
                     -Location westeurope `
                     -SubnetId $subnetid
$nic1.NetworkSecurityGroup = $sg[1]
$nic1 | Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface
```

Comment: Your help is highly appreciated.